# [Check my homework]Electronics homework - op amp and transistor

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, diodes, homework

I'm working on my electronics homework and I'm not sure my logic here is correct. The values are as follows:

\$R1 = 10k\Omega\$,

\$R2 = 1k\Omega\$,

\$V_{D} = 0.6V\$,

\$V_{EB} = 0.6V\$,

\$V_{ECS} = 0.2V\$,

\$\beta_{F} = 100\$,

\$V_{R} = -15V\$.

I need to find \$v_{I}(v_{G})\$ and \$i_{C}(v_{G})\$ in the following two cases:

a) D - ON, Q - cutoff,

b) D - OFF, Q - forward active.
[image: Circuit diagram]

a)Since the transistor is in cutoff state in the first case, there is no current through it, therefore \$i_{C} = 0\$. The plus connector of the opamp is grounded, therefore the potential of the minus connector is 0 as well. Now I can write the following equation:

\$\frac{v_{G} - 0}{R_1} = \frac{0-v_{i}}{R_1} \Rightarrow v_{I}(v_{G}) = -v_{G}\$

b)The transistor is in forward active state which means that \$V_{EB} = v_{I} = 0.6V\$.

\$i_{E} = \frac{v_{G} - V{EB}}{2\cdot R_{1}} = \frac{v_{G}}{20k} - 30\mu\$

\$i_{E} = (\beta_{F} + 1)\cdot i_{B} \Rightarrow i_{B} = \frac{i_{E}}{\beta_{F} + 1}\$

\$i_{C} = i_{E} - i_{B} = \frac{v_{G}}{20k} - 30\mu - \frac{v_{G}}{20k \cdot 101} - 0.3\mu = \frac{v_{G}}{20k}\cdot\left(1 - \frac{1}{101} - 30.3\mu\right)\$

Expression in the last bracket is approximately 1, so \$i_{C} = \frac{v_{G}}{20k}\$.

Are there any mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with diode, transistors and basically anything that has different models depending on different operating points, you **always** have to verify that your starting assumptions are compatible with the solution you have got. If this is not the case, your starting assumptions were wrong.

Let's start with your first case. It looks very promising, but have you thought about the direction of the current in the diode? When it is forward biased, current can go only in one direction. Is this the case for any \$v_G\$?

In your second case you do not calculate \$v_I(v_G)\$, because **\$v_{EB}\$ does not equal \$v_I\$**.

Some help follows:

**SPOILER 1:**

> If \$v_G\$=0 both the transistor and the diode are off, if it is positive only the transistor is on, if it is negative only the diode is on.

**SPOILER 2:**

> The opamp output makes a steps when \$v_G\$ changes sign.

If you **really** can't make it, try to simulate the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUEEjz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I know that generally I need to check assumptions, but in this case these are not assumptions, they are states given by the instructor for which I need to determine the output signal, assuming they are correct. If I understand your post correctly, since no current can flow through the diode in my first case, the circuit is not closed and \$v_{I} = 0\$(the potential of the negative input of the opamp)?

I still don't understand why is \$v_{I}\$ not equal to \$V_{EB}\$ in my second case though.

Thank you for your answer, I have upvoted it, but since my reputation is low it doesn't show up.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome! I understand that these are given conditions, but treating them as assumptions, and verify them, can help you to understand if your results are correct. Your first case is right, but only under certain input conditions, while for the second case Vi = Ve, Veb = Ve-Vb != Vi = Ve unless Vb = 0, which is a very special case.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand. Your simulation has been very helpful, thanks to it I've been able to come to the conclusion that in my second case \$v_{I} = -v_{G}\$ (essentially the same as in the first case), except that it will be true for \$v_{G} > 0\$, as you pointed out, while the collector current is \$i_{C} = 0.99 \cdot \frac{v_{G}}{10k}\$. Thank you!